# Google Places API returns Error: Network Error when using Axios

Tags: javascript, axios, google-places-api

When use python requests and send the following

```
outs = requests.get("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=32.78257453407587,-117.11499507124117&radius=15000&keyword=Paddle+Board+Rentals&key=MY_KEY")
```

I get a status 200 and results.

When I issue with Axios

```
    async getPlaces(point, radius, keywords, type=""){
        const url = this.urlBuilder(point, radius, keywords, type);
        const response = await axios.get(url)
            .then(res => {return res})
            .catch(err => {return err});
        return response
    }
```

And the url is the exact same in the python above, I get

```
Error: Network Error
```

Is there a default header in python that could be causing the difference between the two requests?

Edit:
Using console.log I was able to get this error

Error: Cross origin http://localhost forbidden

So there's an issue from running google places request with fetch or axios because they are coming from local host.

Comment: Can you share your `urlBuilder` function?

Comment: You're not meant to be using `.then()` or `.catch()` with `async` and the contents of those methods are silly anyway. Also, you don't need to use `axios` for things like this -- you can use `fetch()`. To make sure that the URL is the same, why not put it in a `console.log`, just to be sure?

Comment: I grabbed the url from a Webstorm breakpoint.  The python request uses the exact url that axios is using.

Comment: I highly recommend using the [Maps JS SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places) instead of attempting to make direct requests

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that google will not allow users to make these network calls over https with javascript.  You must use the google places api.